# Show that every short exact sequence $0\rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ (with $M''$ free) is split exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, exact-sequence

Note: $M,M',M''$ are modules.

In order to show that it's split exact, I understand that I need to show that $\beta:M\rightarrow M''$ has a left inverse, and similarly that $\alpha:M'\rightarrow M$ has a right inverse. I also understand that $M''$ must have a generating set (as it's free).

$\alpha$ is a monomorphism (as the sequence is exact), so I'd imagine that as it's 1-1 it must have an inverse. I'm not sure about what to do with $\beta$ though, as I only know it's an epimorphism.

EDIT: here I'm writing my function as $x(f)$ rather than $f(x)$

Comment: Monomorphisms do not necessarily have right inverses. Consider $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $n \mapsto 2n$... Instead, try to work on $M''$, since it's the only thing you have knowledge about: what does it mean for $M''$ to be free?

Comment: Do you know about projective modules?

Comment: I think you mixed up left and right. Unless you write function application $(x)\beta$ rather than $\beta(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that's how I normally write them. I'll edit the post now to make it clearer.

Comment: @Simon I'm afraid I don't. Do I need to know about them to solve this?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt No, knowing a couple of facts about free modules is sufficient. The scalar ring is unital, I suppose?

Comment: @DanielFischer It doesn't say.

Comment: As a hint  - why would this sequence split if the modules were vector spaces i.e., if the base ring were a field?

Comment: @peterag in that case every element would have an inverse. However, we don't know that that is the case here just from $M''$ being free, do we?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module. I had in mind the first line...

Comment: And maybe my hint was misleading - but how would you prove the result if $M''= k$, where $k$ is the base (unital) ring?

Comment: In that case $\beta$ would be an inclusion mapping?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25358/discussion-between-man-in-green-shirt-and-peter-a-g).

Comment: Are you not 'chat'-ing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answer from a discussion with @peter a g)

Our objective is to form a homomorphism from $M''$ to $M$.

Call $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ a basis of the free module $M''$. As it is a basis, every element of $M''$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements in a unique way.

At this point, we construct our homomorphism from $M''$ to $M$ by first choosing the elements $a_i$ of $M$ that map to the elements of the basis $e_i$ under $\beta$, then defining our homomorphism by mapping each element $e_i$ of the basis to an $a_i$ and then extending this map so the domain is the whole of $M''$.

Comment: Point of terminology: $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ is **a**  basis of $M''$, not **the** basis, because there are (usually) multiple different bases.